# Three.js get center of Scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

What I want to do is to get the center of a Scene obtained from ColladaLoader (as the loaded model is the Scene) in Three.js and then set is as the target of Camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gaitat's solution will work as long as the model's origin just so happens to also be its center, but I don't think that's likely to be the case. The origin of the model might be the bottom left corner, or the middle of the top plane, or any other point that has no relation to the "center" of the model.

To get the "center" of a model, you need to calculate it from its geometry. Fortunately, THREE.Geometry has some convenience methods to help with that. You can calculate the "bounding sphere" for geometry, i.e. the smallest possible sphere that fits in all the geometry's points. The center of that bounding sphere will be the "center" of the total geometry.

```
var mesh; // this should be your model's mesh
          // it might be buried inside the DAE object somewhere

mesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere(); // this isn't calculated automatically
                                       // you need to call it

mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.center; // THREE.Vector3 which is the center of the sphere
```

I'm not sure if you'll need to compute the world matrix transformation for the resulting boundingSphere.center or not, but it's a start.

Keep in mind that the bounding sphere for a geometry doesn't account for the distribution of points. A single solitary point in the geometry that is very very far away from the others will throw off the center of the bounding sphere because it needs to shift to include that point. Still, the bounding sphere method is the quickest and easiest method and should work in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this. The point is the Dae scene contains multiple meshes. How to calculate the center then?

Comment: @Artus90 then why not find the bounding spheres of all the relevant meshes and then average them together? If that's not what you want then you need to be much more specific about what you mean by the "center" of your scene.

Comment: On the scene, there are about 1000 meshes, which together make a building. I read on the forums that ColladaLoader loads the whole Three.Scene into returned object. I want to center the camera in the center of all the meshes contained in the returned scene.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `camera.lookAt(scene.position);`